# Cant get my code to Print out depending on different statements in Python

Tags: python

I have tried else and elif statements but nothing works any ideas?

```
import random


choice = input(" Witch one did u pick Rock , Paper or Scissors?")
print(choice)


computer = ["R", "P", "S"]
print(random.choice(computer))


if choice == "R" and random.choice(computer) == "R":
    print("Sorry its a tie")

if choice == "R" and random.choice(computer) == "P":
        print("Sorry Will wins")
```

Comment: What happens if `random.choice(computer)` gives you `S`?

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `random.choice(computer)` everytime, this can give different results in different calls to the function. You should only call it once, and then save that result and use it in the `if..elif` . Also you should use `if..elif` , not `if..if` .

```
import random

choice = input(" Witch one did u pick Rock , Paper or Scissors?")
print(choice)
```

```
import random
computer = ["R", "P", "S"]
choosen = random.choice(computer)
print(choosen)


if choice == "R" and choosen == "R":
    print("Sorry its a tie")
elif choice == "R" and choosen == "P":
        print("Sorry Will wins")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the top. First you say:

```
choice = input("Witch one did u pick Rock, Paper or Scissors?)
print(choice)
```

Because you are printing this decision out it may help with user experience and debugging to instead write:

```
print("User Choice: " + choice)
```

Moving on:

```
computer = ["R", "P", "S"]
print(random.choice(computer))
```

From a user standpoint if you're going to print this out you want to match the same style as before and write:

```
computer = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
```

And from a programming standpoint you're going to want to save the result of the random choice in a variable so you can use it later, because calling random.choice again will create new answers. So a good way of approaching this would be:

```
computerDecision = random.choice(computer)
print("Computer Choice: " + computerDecision)
```

Finally you have your if statements. First you are checking:

```
if choice == "R"
```

The problem with this is earlier in your code you wrote:

```
choice = input(" Witch one did u pick Rock , Paper or Scissors?")
```

Meaning the output would most likely be ("Rock", "Paper" or "Scissors") not ("R", "P" or "S") so you would want:

```
if choice == "Rock"
```

And you use the same if statement twice so you can can just make a nested if and use your variable from earlier:

```
if choice == "Rock":
    if computerDecision == "Rock":
        print("Sorry its a tie")
    elif computerDecision == "Paper":
        print("Sorry Will wins")
    elif computerDecision == "Scissors":
        print("You win")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

You would need to make this for "Paper" and "Scissors" as well.
That final else statement simply covers the scenario of the user inputting something besides "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors"